# Notepad+: Adding a Python Function parser / Function List

Tags: python, notepad++

Are there any improvements that could be made to this?

From ArtFunkel on SourceForge:

http://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/discussion/482781/thread/515001cd/#31ae

```
    <parser id="py_function" displayName="Python class" commentExpr="(#.*?$|'''.*?('''|\Z))">
        <classRange mainExpr="(?<=^class ).*?(?=\n\S|\Z)">
            <className>
                <nameExpr expr="\w+(?=[\(|:])"/>
            </className>
            <function mainExpr="(?<=def ).+?(?=:)">
                <functionName>
                    <funcNameExpr expr=".*"/>
                </functionName>
            </function>
        </classRange>
        <function mainExpr="(?<=def ).+?(?=:)">
            <functionName>
                <funcNameExpr expr=".*"/>
            </functionName>
        </function>
    </parser>
```

The function list doesn't do nested classes, but otherwise the parser above should pick up everything!
Insert the element into %appdata%\Notepad++\functionList.xml, then add this line to associationMap to register the association:

```
    <association langID="22" id="py_function"/>
```